# Is it possible to relay the logs from a docker container to more than one server using gelf?

Tags: docker, gelf

Currently, I have a docker container sending logs to a Logstash using gelf. Pretty standard configuration set in the docker-compose file used to create the container.

I'm investigating the feasibility of sending the logs of a docker container to more than one instance of ELK. This is not needed for production, but will greatly improve the quality of life of our dev teams.

Reading [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/), it seems that what i need is not possible (at least, they don't mention whether the `gelf-address` property accepts a list of URIs or not, and I must assume it doesn't while I look for more info).

Does anyone know if this can be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at docker's code [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/daemon/logger/gelf/gelf.go#L39) and [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/daemon/logger/gelf/gelf.go#L246) I'd say that currently only a single target address is supported.

```
// New creates a gelf logger using the configuration passed in on the
// context. The supported context configuration variable is gelf-address.
func New(info logger.Info) (logger.Logger, error) {
    // parse gelf address
    address, err := parseAddress(info.Config["gelf-address"])
```

Potentially, this project [andviro/grayproxy](https://github.com/andviro/grayproxy#usage) looks like it could help you take a single GELF input, and forward it to multiple GELF collectors:

> By default grayproxy configures the input at udp://0.0.0.0:12201 and no outputs. Outputs are added using -out flag *and may be specified multiple times*

Comment: Thank you, James, for your time and your answer. I hadn't the time to dive into the code, yet it is nice to see that their docs do well in suggesting that it is not possible :) I didn't know Grayproxy, thanks for that pointer too!